# Emacs syntax highlight for subtitle files like as .srt .smi

Tags: emacs, subtitle, srt

I found that Emacs has a mode for subtitle files like as `.srt` `.smi`.
However it doesn't do any syntax highlighting on those sort of files.

If there's a way to do that, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This mode https://github.com/naokiri/subtitle-mode/blob/master/subtitle-mode.el seems to do syntax highlighgting for numbers, time and text.

Besides it can read the movie (with `mplayer2`) starting from where the cursor is.

Comment: Thanks it works for srt files but doen't for smi files.